# Spring boot 2 database with jpaRepositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I create one app with use 2 databases, but in my test I need to create this class:

```
@Repository
public class UsuarioRegistroRep {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "dbregistro")
    EntityManager em;

    public List<TbUsuarioDbRegistro> findAll() {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM TbUsuarioDbRegistro t ").getResultList();
    }
}
```

Can I use the interface JpaRespository or CrudRepository so I don`t need to override all basic methods ( findAll, findOne,...)

this is my Configuration Class:

```
package br.com.lumera.config;


import br.com.lumera.entity.TbUsuarioDbRegistro;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "dbregistroEntityManagerFactory")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DbRegistroConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.dbregistro")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dbregistroEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(secondaryDataSource())
                .packages(TbUsuarioDbRegistro.class)
                .persistenceUnit("dbregistro")
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager dbRegistroTransactionManager(@Qualifier("dbregistroEntityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory)
    {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }
}
```

tks

I try to create one interface

```
public interface UsuarioDnaRepo extends CrudRepository<TbUsuarioDbDnaso, Integer>{
}
```

and then autowired then

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dnaso")
public class UsuarioDnaso {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioDnaRepo UsuarioDnaRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<TbUsuarioDbDnaso> testar(){
        return (List<TbUsuarioDbDnaso>) UsuarioDnaRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

but I got this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioDnaso': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: br.com.lumera.repositories.UsuarioDnaRepo br.com.lumera.web.UsuarioDnaso.UsuarioDnaRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.lumera.repositories.UsuarioDnaRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at br.com.lumera.Application.main(Application.java:44) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: br.com.lumera.repositories.UsuarioDnaRepo br.com.lumera.web.UsuarioDnaso.UsuarioDnaRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.lumera.repositories.UsuarioDnaRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.lumera.repositories.UsuarioDnaRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Yes, you can use Spring Data repositories in your tests, so long as you configure them properly.  Is this not working for you?  What have you tried?

Comment: [This demo](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/demo-multi-entity-managers) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, but my application doesn't find others @Service annotated classes ... Help

Comment: Ok, I needed to declare @ComponentScan(basePackages ={ "com.project.service"}). I don't know why Spring Boot doesn't find them automatically ...